# Do I have to return something in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, function, return

In JavaScript functions, do I need to return something (true or false) ? So far, all the functions I wrote without returning anything work just fine. I'm just curious.

Comment: They work just fine unless you are expecting them to return anything other than `undefined` ;-) But, I think the question sort of answered itself.

Comment: Also, just because a function does return something doesn't mean you have to do anything with the returned value.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No; Javascript functions are not required to return a value.

If you call a function that doesn't `return` a value, you'll get `undefined` as the return value.

Comment: Same goes for functions that has `return;` in them.

Comment: And functions that can exit with out executing one of its returns.

Comment: I think perhaps "if you call a function and `return` is not executed.." or ... "if control runs off the end of the function without encountering `return`" or ...

Answer (score 2):

no you dont.  I believe if you do

```
var result = iAmADefinedFunctionThatDoesntReturnAnything();
```

result will be undefined.

Edit, this screenshot should be illuminating (forgive the mistake when i fail to invoke f):

[image]

Comment: Actually, as you haven't defined the function, it throws ReferenceError.

Comment: @hello71.  Look at the top.  Line 1.  var f = function(){} certainly defines a function

Comment: Also, you should really use typeof to determine undefined.

Comment: @hello71, right, i was hoping that we could intuit that functionThatDoesntReturnAnything() is actually a defined function that does not return anything. ;)

Comment: @hello71, ok how about now? ;)

Answer (score 1):

No you don't

**BUT** 
if you find yourself doing something like this

```
 function myFun(){
   if (1 == 2){
    return true ;
   }
 }
```

Now you should know you are doing something wrong in your code because it doesn't make sense that only  part of the function return a value

Comment: Why won't it make sense? For example if you want to populate a list with a search term and it isn't found then you might as well give nothing back.

Comment: Becuase the if condition is always evaluated to be null, which we call a dead code