# Javascript returning correct & undefined value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Sorry the title is vague, but I have a form that accepts multiple id and posts the users input to URL to open x amount of tabs depending on the number of account id's.

The link for the first account id is opening with the values inserted into the form but the second account id is just showing "undefined" and from console looks like the second account id isn't getting past the first declaration but skipping to the second.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
            <table class="vat-tax-processor center-table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span class="required">*</span>
                            AWS Account ID (No Dashes)<br>
                        </td>
                        <td><textarea autocomplete="off" id="AccountIDs" name="AccountIDs" value=""></textarea></td>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span class="required">*</span>
                            VAT Country <br>
                        </td>
                        <td><input autocomplete="off" type="text" value="" id="vatCountryCode" name="vatCountryCode"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span class="required">*</span>
                            Vat Number<br>
                        </td>
                        <td><input autocomplete="off" type="text" value="" id="vatNumber" name="vatNumber"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span class="required">*</span>
                            Registration Type <br>
                        </td>
                        <td><input autocomplete="off" type="text" value="Intra-EU" id="currentState" name="currentState"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span class="required">*</span>
                            Business Legal Name <br>
                        </td>
                        <td><input autocomplete="off" type="text" value="" id="businessLegalName" name="businessLegalName"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
```

Here is my js:

```
function addExemption(){
        var AccountIDsArray = $('textarea[id=AccountIDs]').val().split('\n');
        var vatCountryCodeArray = $('input[id=vatCountryCode]').val().split('\n');
        var vatNumberArray = $('input[id=vatNumber]').val().split('\n');
        /*var currentStateArray = $('input[id=currentState]').val().split('\n');*/
        var businessLegalNameArray = $('input[id=businessLegalName]').val().split('\n');
        console.log('I got past part 1 declarations - No issues here');

        $.each(AccountIDsArray, function(index, value){
            var AccountID = AccountIDsArray[index];
            var vatCountryCode = vatCountryCodeArray[index];
            var vatNumber = vatNumberArray[index];
            /*var currentState = currentStateArray[index];*/
            var businessLegalName = businessLegalNameArray[index];
            console.log('I got part part 2 declarations - No issues here either');
            console.log(AccountID);

            var URL = 'https://linkhere';

            var URL_Final = encodeURI(URL);

            window.open(URL_Final, '_blank');



        }
);
```

Here is a screenshot of what appears on first link and second link:

[Account 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9xww.png)
[Account 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GeEg.png)

Comment: Give us the input, otherwise its only guesswork

Comment: side note: provided that the ids are unique (which they should be ;) ), it's easier (and more efficient) to use `#id` instead of the `..[id=..` construction. e.g. `$('#AccountIDs).val()`

Comment: @Deckerz The inputs come from an html form which I've added above.

Comment: @Me.Name Thanks for that :) makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this like so:

```
function addExemption(){


        var AccountIDsArray = $('textarea[id=AccountIDs]').val().split('\n');
        console.log('I got past 1st declarations - No issues here');


        $.each(AccountIDsArray, function(index, value){
            var AccountID = AccountIDsArray[index];
            var vatCountryCode = $('#vatCountryCode').val();
            var vatNumber = $('#vatNumber').val();
            var businessLegalName = $('#businessLegalName').val();
            console.log('I got past 2nd declarations - No issues here either');
            console.log(AccountID);

            var URL = 'https:xxxxx?accountId=' + AccountID + '&vatCountryCode=' + vatCountryCode + '&vatNumber=' + vatNumber + '&currentState=Intra-EU&businessLegalName=' + businessLegalName + '';

            var URL_Final = encodeURI(URL);

            window.open(URL_Final, '_blank');

        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues I see with this.

The window is opening in your loop meaning that it will open a window immediately after the first id is printed to the console. I would move window.open() outside of the $.each.

You are risking out of bounds indexing on vatCountryCodeArray, vatNumberArray, currentStateArray and businessLegalNameArray since they are input elements and not textareas.

The 'Undefined' you see if because your function has no return value. [See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337064/does-every-javascript-function-have-to-return-a-value)

```js
function addExemption(){
        var AccountIDsArray = $('textarea[id=AccountIDs]').val().split('\n');
        var vatCountryCodeArray = $('textarea[id=vatCountryCode]').val().split('\n');
        var vatNumberArray = $('textarea[id=vatNumber]').val().split('\n');
        var currentStateArray = $('textarea[id=currentState]').val().split('\n');
        var businessLegalNameArray = $('textarea[id=businessLegalName]').val().split('\n');
        console.log('I got past part 1 declarations - No issues here');

        $.each(AccountIDsArray, function(index, value){
            if(value != null && value != ''){
                var AccountID = value;
                //var vatCountryCode = vatCountryCodeArray[index];
                //var vatNumber = vatNumberArray[index];
                //var currentState = currentStateArray[index];
                //var businessLegalName = businessLegalNameArray[index];

                console.log('I got part part 2 declarations - No issues here either');
                console.log(AccountID);
            }
        });

        var URL = 'https://linkhere';

        var URL_Final = encodeURI(URL);

        window.open(URL_Final,'_blank');

        return '';
}
```

Comment: I should mention the url being called looks like this:     `var URL = 'https:/xxxxx?accountId=' + AccountID + '&vatCountryCode=' + vatCountryCode + '&vatNumber=' + vatNumber + '&currentState=Intra-EU&businessLegalName=' ';`    so with your code AccountID isn't being called because it's outside of the loop I think