# What my code display this?

Tags: javascript

I've just started learning javascript and I've write a code that display at the end of the output undefined?
why?

```js
var laugh = function laughs(y) {

  while (y > 0) {

    console.log("ha");
    y--;

  }

  console.log("ha!");
}

console.log(laugh(10));
```

And this is the output:

```
ha
ha
ha
ha
ha
ha
ha
ha
ha
ha
ha!
undefined
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does every Javascript function have to return a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337064/does-every-javascript-function-have-to-return-a-value)

Answer (score 2):

`laugh` doesn't return anything and by default a function will return `undefined`, and that will pass into your last `console.log` call.

Answer (score 0):

Because the function `laugh` doesn't return any value, so the result is `undefined`.

Look the modification to return `"HELLO"`, this is just to illustrate.

```js
var laugh = function laughs(y) {
  while (y > 0) {
    console.log("ha");
    y--;
  }

  console.log("ha!");

  return "HELLO";
}

console.log(laugh(10));
```

Comment: @trincot There is any repeat, that code illustrates what I'm answering.  Look carefully the `return "HELLO"`.

Comment: The modified version is OK now ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`laugh()` does not explicitly return a value; therefore its return type is `undefined`. You're calling `laugh()` from within a `console.log()` - the result being that you see all the `console.log()` calls that occur within `laugh()` then, additionally, the `undefined` being returned by `laugh()` is being logged to the console.

You could return a string if you want to log the result of the function. Something like this:

```js
var laugh = function laughs(y) {
  var str = '';
  while (y > 0) {
    //console.log("ha");
    str += 'ha\n';
    y--;
  }
  //console.log("ha!");
  str += 'ha!\n';
  return str;
}

console.log(laugh(10));
```

Alternatively, you could just remove the `console.log()` enclosing the function call like this:

```js
var laugh = function laughs(y) {
  while (y > 0) {
    console.log("ha");
    y--;
  }
  console.log("ha!");
}

laugh(10);
```