# Execute javascript 'undefined' output but it work as expected

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, awesomium

I am trying to click a button from a website

This is the code of that website

```
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="submit" class="buttons">
```

I use awesomium and c# to do this

And below is my sample code

```
wb.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult(@"document.getElementsByName('Submit')[0].click();");
```

In my output log of Visual studio the result is 'undefined' but it click the button in the website and it generates output as expected. But i want to learn the reason of the error. But it doesn't give me any more error.

In order to check if its an error of awesomium. I load the website in google chrome and executed the javascript in the console and the output is the same. it gives me `undefined` but it clicks the button and generate output.

I don't have much knowledge of javascript. But how can i solve this kind of issue?

Regards,
Meco

Comment: When a method does not have an explicit return value, undefined is returned by default. Nothing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a **function** does not have an explicit return value, `undefined` is returned by default. Nothing wrong here.

[More info here, awesome answer by the way !](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17337268/2880747)

Comment: so in c# the method that is called is void? Thank you. I understand it now.

Comment: Pretty much yes :)!