# Javascript function: no return statement identical to return undefined?

Tags: javascript

```
var f1 = () => {
    return undefined;
};

var f2 = () => {
};

var a = f1(); // undefined
var b = f2(); // undefined
```

I know the results but I want to know more in-depth. Is that mean in Javascript functions, no return statement identical to return `undefined`?

Comment: Well, there's no return value. How would you call a return value that has not been defined? :)

Comment: Yes it is. ... ...

Comment: Every expression results in a value, otherwise it would be a statement. A function call is an expression. The value for "no value" is `undefined`.

Comment: @deceze what is statement and expression

Comment: A statement is something like `for (...)`; you can only use it by itself, it does not result in a value. An expression is something that results in a value and can be used as part of a larger expression or statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know the results but I want to know more in-depth. Is that mean in Javascript functions, no `return` statement identical to `return undefined`?

It is *in effect*, yes. The specification differentiates between the two, but in pragmatic terms, calling a function that "falls off the end" vs. `return;` vs. `return undefined;` all have exactly the same end result in terms of what have the call results in: `undefined`.

In [my answer to the dupetarget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51059727/157247) *(I should have realized!)* I explain how the spec differentiates them, but again, it's just a spec distinction, not something you can observe in actual code.

Answer (score 3):

It depends.

For functions who are not used as an instance the default return value is `undefined`.

For a constructor, called with `new`, it returns `this` object as default.

Sources:

- [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)
- [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#Description)
- [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

Answer (score 1):

If there is no return the return value will be *undefined* it's basically the same as doing return; (without value) since the function will "return" when it is finised (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return for information to return)

If you initialize a function (more like a class) than the returned value will be the instance of this function instead.