# How to Ensure Data is Returned Before Variable Assignment (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I am trying to retrieve data at multiple API endpoints simultaneously and aggregate the result to be sent back to the client as one response.

However, when trying to return data from `async.parallel`, I get an `undefined` result.  I think this is because the `result` code is being executed before it is returned, but I am not sure.

I would like to pass an array of ids to the server, get their metadata, combine their metadata into one object, and send a single object back to the client.

```
function doSomething() {
  for(let i=0; i<req.map.length; i++) {
    stack[i] = (callback) => {
      let data = subroute(req, res, req.map[i])
      callback(null, data)
    }
  }

  async.parallel(stack, (err, result) => {
    if(err) {
      // Handle error
    } else {
      console.log(result) // Logs undefined
      res.json([result])  // Would like to send this result back to the client
    }
  })
}

function subroute(req, res, num) {
  request({
    url: 'https://example.com/api/endpoint/' + num
  },
  (error, response, body) => {
    if(error) {
      res.json({ "error": error })
    } else {
      let i = {
        name: body.name,
        age: body.age,
      }
      return i 
    }
  })
}
```

How can I accumulate the results of many API endpoint responses on the server and send the back as one response to the client?

Comment: I think too that the return is not catched up. Add a callback argument to `subroute` and call it in `request`'s callback. Pass a function to `subroute` in `task`, which will call the `callback(null, data)` there

Comment: You should pass the callback to subroute function and trigger it from there once you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
let data = subroute(req, res, req.map[i])
callback(null, data)
```

to

```
subroute(req, res, req.map[i], callback)
```

Subsequently, change subroute to receive the callback and return the return

```
function subroute(req, res, num, cb) {
 request({
    url: 'https://example.com/api/endpoint/' + num
  },
  (error, response, body) => {
    if(error) {
      res.json({ "error": error })
      cb(<whatever error you would want to pass>);
    } else {
      let i = {
        name: body.name,
        age: body.age,
      }
      cb(null, i);
    }
  })
}
```

By doing `let data = subroute(req, res, req.map[i])` you are assigning the result of `subroute` call to `data`. Notice `subroute` does not have a `return` statement in the function body so data will always be `undefined`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on: Notice `subroute` does not have a `return` statement in the function body so data will always be `undefined`?

Comment: It is implicitly returning `undefined`. A function body without a return statement can be seen as having `return undefined` as the last statement. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337064/does-every-javascript-function-have-to-return-a-value

Comment: So, if I'm understanding correctly, each parameter that is passed into a function has its own return value?

Comment: No. A function can only return once. If there is no return statement in a function, it is implied that it returns the default value, which happens to be `undefined` in case of JavaScript. For the same case in python, it returns `None`.

Comment: OK. So by `body`, you were referring to the function body, and not the `body` parameter that is being passed into the if/else block?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote as well.

Comment: OK. Thank you for clarification and help on this!