# Behavior for single if condition (omitting else return false)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement

I was able to omit the `else return false` for this React lifecycle method and still have it work as desired, returning false for odd numbers (`value` increments by 1 from 0 -- see freeCodeCamp [challenge](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/front-end-libraries/react/optimize-re-renders-with-shouldcomponentupdate/) for the rest of the code), but I'm not clear on why it works this way.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    console.log('Should I update?');
    if (nextProps.value % 2 == 0) return true;
  }
```

Since `shouldComponentUpdate` defaults to true per React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate), I thought it might still return true even for odd values. I guess the default only applies when there is no condition specified whatsoever.

If an if condition that returns true isn't met and no other conditions are provided, does JavaScript always return false?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does every Javascript function have to return a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337064/does-every-javascript-function-have-to-return-a-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *If an if condition that returns true isn't met and no other conditions are provided, does JavaScript always return false?*

The short and literal answer is ***no***. JavaScript values (even booleans) can be evaluated as [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) or [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

With this said, lets try to analyze what is happening in your component method.

- A JavaScript function with no `return` statement evaluates to `undefined`.
- `shouldComponentUpdate` in React expects a boolean value.
- Since the function returned `undefined`, it is evaluated as a *falsy* value automatically.
- Then the component isn't updated due to the *falsy* value return.

My recommendation:

#### Take control of your code.

Avoid unexpected behaviors like this since it may change in future versions of React.

Why not a [ternary conditional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)?:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
   return (nextProps.value % 2 == 0 ? true : false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript values are always "truthy" or "falsely"... the return type in the not true case here is void which is "falsey", along with false, null, undefined (anything assigned via this function would become undefined in the falsey case), 0 and empty string.