# How can I log this function constructor value?

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, function-constructor

I work with JS in Brackets, and when I refresh this section, the value of the Carbo is correct in the console. But, when I try this in that console.log, the google console just write ,undefined'.

**Why** and how can i solve this problem?

Here is my lil' practice program.

```
var Foods = function(name, priceWithDollar, makingTimeMin) {
    this.name = name;
    this.priceWithDollar = priceWithDollar;
    this.makingTimeMin = makingTimeMin;
}

Foods.prototype.priceChangeToHUF = function() {
    console.log(this.priceWithDollar * 326);
}

var carbonara = new Foods('Carbonara', 10.91, 10);

carbonara.priceChangeToHUF();
console.log('The carbonara\'s price is ' + carbonara.priceChangeToHUF() + '.');
```

Thank you for the help.

Adam

**!One other thing!**
Just right now, when I wrote these lines, something came to my mind.
That value of the prototype (326) is actually not dynamic.
But I have an idea. I have to write that actually value from the first google page, when i check the ,1 dollar to huf'.

How do I get started?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `priceChangeToHUF` is not returning a value. The following should work:

```
Foods.prototype.priceChangeToHUF = function() {
    console.log(this.priceWithDollar * 326);
    return this.priceWithDollar * 326;
}
```

More information about default return values here: [Does every Javascript function have to return a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337064/does-every-javascript-function-have-to-return-a-value)

For your currency conversion, it'd probably be easier to fetch this value directly from an API instead of scraping it from Google results. This page has some good info: [How do I get currency exchange rates via an API such as Google Finance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139879/how-do-i-get-currency-exchange-rates-via-an-api-such-as-google-finance)