# Why watcher is better than computed to perform asynchronous or expensive operations in response to changing data in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Documentation of `Vue.js` says:

Using the `watch` option allows us to perform an asynchronous operation (accessing an API), limit how often we perform that operation, and set intermediary states until we get a final answer. None of that would be possible with a `computed` property.

While on the same page, we can see that `computed` property uses a function the same as `watcher`.

**Reference:** https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property

So my question is what is the technical reason supporting the above statement or limiting us from using `computed` properties instead of `watchers`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's important to understand how `computed` properties work in Vue. In most cases what developer gives to Vue is a **getter** which is a function, which defines how the value of computed property is computed.

1. When the `computed` prop getter (function provided by you) is running, Vue is monitoring which other reactive `data` is accessed so it knows on what data the result depends
2. Result of the getter is cached by Vue
3. Whenever you access the value of the `computed` prop, small chunk of Vue code is executed - it first checks whether it has value in the cache and if yes, whether some of the inputs changed from the last time the getter was executed. If there is a value and no changes, the getter is not executed at all and cached value is returned instead

Title of your question mentions "asynchronous or expensive" ...

### Expensive

Expensive computation is **exactly** what `computed` props are for because the getter is executed **only** when needed. But it is executed **every time** something changes, which is not always what you want. So the docs are talking about use cases when you have some stream of values - let's say user typing - and you want perform the operation only after she stops for 200ms. Or you have some stream of data (telemetry) but want to update the graph only every 2 seconds

This is not possible with `computed` because Vue **expects getter to return value every time and that value is stored in the cache for future use**.

### Asynchronous

As I said before, Vue expects the `computed` getter to return a value. When you run some async call inside `computed` prop getter, you have no value to return (in case of asynchrony based on callbacks - but [JS functions always return something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337064/does-every-javascript-function-have-to-return-a-value)) or you have a promise of the future value. So Vue takes the result of your function (`undefined` or promise) and store it in the cache ...which is something you don't want. So if there is any asynchrony involved, `watch` is always better...

Comment: Good explanation, but to avoid confusion try to use the term property instead of function when you talk about computed

Answer (score 1):

The computed property watches (observes) changes in **other properties** and does calculations based on these properties to **return a value**, in other hand Watcher property observes changes in **one property** and runs **some logic** based on that property and **doesn't return any value**.

So if your use case needs to return a value after doing some calculations use computed, else if you need to run some operations after a property changes you should use watch.

Watcher property could observes the computed property changes because computed one returns a value, but you cannot use a computed property based on watcher one.