# Run function when element enters to viewport with getBoundingClientRect or intersection observer

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to run a function called txtAnim when the element .txt-anim enters to the viewport and want to use getBoundingClientRect or intersection observer

Is that possible? I didn't get it working

(I have the animation working but i want it fired when it enters to the viewport)

```js
function txtAnim(speed){

    jQuery('.txt-anim').css("opacity", "1");

    var skills = jQuery('.txt-anim p').contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType === 3; // only immediate text in div, not in span
    }).map(function() {
        var txt = "<span class='letter'>" + jQuery(this).text().split("").join("</span><span class='letter'>") + "</span>";
        // console.log(txt);
        jQuery(this).replaceWith(txt);
    });

    var i = 0;
    var span = jQuery('.txt-anim').find('span');

    jQuery(".txt-anim p").empty();

    typeWriter();
    function typeWriter() {
        if (i < span.length) {
            jQuery('.txt-anim p').append(span[i]) ;
            i++;
            setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
        }else{
            console.log("text animation ended");
            jQuery('.home-page-cities-mobile').css("opacity", "1");
            jQuery('.flecha-home').css("opacity", "1");
        }
    }

}    
//Intersection Observer
const textAnim = document.querySelector('.txt-anim');
let options = {
  root: textAnim,
  rootMargin: "0px",
  threshold: 1.0
};

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(txtAnim(20), options);

observer.observe(textAnim);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="logo-message txt-anim">
                <p>
                    <span class="letter">L</span>
                    <span class="letter">i</span>
                    <span class="letter">q</span>
                    <span class="letter">u</span>
                    <span class="letter">i</span>
                    <span class="letter">d</span>
                    <span class="letter empty"> </span>
                    <span class="letter">i</span>
                    <span class="letter">d</span>
                    <span class="letter">e</span>
                    <span class="letter">a</span>
                    <span class="letter">s</span>
                    <span class="letter empty"> </span>
                    <span class="letter">t</span>
                    <span class="letter">o</span>
                    <span class="letter empty"> </span>
                    <span class="letter">g</span>
                    <span class="letter">e</span>
                    <span class="letter">t</span>
                    <span class="letter empty"> </span>
                    <span class="letter">a</span>
                    <span class="letter">n</span>
                    <span class="letter">y</span>
                    <span class="letter">w</span>
                    <span class="letter">h</span>
                    <span class="letter">e</span>
                    <span class="letter">r</span>
                    <span class="letter">e</span>
                </p>
            </div>
```

Can anyone help? I've tried with intersection observer beucase i thought it would be easier

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: It may be possible, but without a [mcve] in your question we can't know or help.

Comment: @mitya done! Code posted

Comment: @evolutionxbox done! Code posted

Comment: @Vander that's a good first step, but it's not a complete demo. When we run it there are errors. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Done, sorry man

Comment: What is `txtAnim(20)` supposed to do?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it animates the text, the 20 is the speed, you can see it if you run the code, so i want this function to be fired then the text enters to the viewport

Comment: `IntersectionObserver` requires the first argument to be a callback, but `txtAnim` is being called so the observer is being given `undefined`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox what should i do? i did not understand

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API says that doing `new IntersectionObserver(txtAnim(20), ...` won't work as the first argument needs to be a callable function. `txtAnim(20)` returns undefined which is not a callable function. --- Try `new IntersectionObserver( () => txtAnim(20), ...` instead?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Nope, that didnt work... Don't know why it returns undefined or how cn i make it a callable function

Comment: @Vander saying it didn't work isn't helpful. Please show an example. Besides, that's likely not the only problem here --- As for why the function returns undefined, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337064/does-every-javascript-function-have-to-return-a-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so there's a couple problems with the way you're using intersection observer here.

First, your root is wrong. You're using the same element for `root` as you're trying to observe, which means you're asking the question, `When does this element intersect with itself?` which is obviously not a very useful question.

If you want it to show when you've scrolled to it in the viewport, you actually don't need to specify a root at all.

Secondly, you're not checking the thing you really need to check: the `isIntersecting` property. When the intersection observer callback fires, the first argument is an array of `entries`, and each entry has an `isIntersecting` property which can be true or false.

I've made this jsfiddle that maybe comes close to doing what you want.

https://jsfiddle.net/xapjz2fe/

As you can see, i've also added in a check to make sure the function `txtAnim` doesn't run itself more than once -- without that check, if you scrolled to the element, then scrolled away and scrolled back, `txtAnim` would run a second time and it would mess everything up.

```js
let txtAnimStarted = false;
function txtAnim(speed){
        if (txtAnimStarted) return;
    txtAnimStarted = true;
        console.log('starting txtAnim');
    jQuery('.txt-anim').css("opacity", "1");

    var skills = jQuery('.txt-anim p').contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType === 3; // only immediate text in div, not in span
    }).map(function() {
        var txt = "<span class='letter'>" + jQuery(this).text().split("").join("</span><span class='letter'>") + "</span>";
        // console.log(txt);
        jQuery(this).replaceWith(txt);
    });

    var i = 0;
    var span = jQuery('.txt-anim').find('span');

    jQuery(".txt-anim p").empty();

    typeWriter();
    function typeWriter() {
        if (i < span.length) {
            jQuery('.txt-anim p').append(span[i]) ;
            i++;
            setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
        }else{
            console.log("text animation ended");
            jQuery('.home-page-cities-mobile').css("opacity", "1");
            jQuery('.flecha-home').css("opacity", "1");
        }
    }

}    
//Intersection Observer
const textAnim = document.querySelector('.txt-anim');
let options = {
  rootMargin: "0px",
  threshold: 1.0
};

let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    const entry = entries[0];
  if (entry.isIntersecting) txtAnim(20);
}, options);

observer.observe(textAnim);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="margin-bottom:1000px">top div, scroll down</div>

<div class="logo-message txt-anim" style="padding-bottom:20px">
  <p>
    <span class="letter">L</span>
    <span class="letter">i</span>
    <span class="letter">q</span>
    <span class="letter">u</span>
    <span class="letter">i</span>
    <span class="letter">d</span>
    <span class="letter empty"> </span>
    <span class="letter">i</span>
    <span class="letter">d</span>
    <span class="letter">e</span>
    <span class="letter">a</span>
    <span class="letter">s</span>
    <span class="letter empty"> </span>
    <span class="letter">t</span>
    <span class="letter">o</span>
    <span class="letter empty"> </span>
    <span class="letter">g</span>
    <span class="letter">e</span>
    <span class="letter">t</span>
    <span class="letter empty"> </span>
    <span class="letter">a</span>
    <span class="letter">n</span>
    <span class="letter">y</span>
    <span class="letter">w</span>
    <span class="letter">h</span>
    <span class="letter">e</span>
    <span class="letter">r</span>
    <span class="letter">e</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

My indentation of the javascript got ruined copying over from jsfiddle, sorry about that

Comment: Good answer, nicely demonstrated.

Comment: That was really helpful man :) Really appreciated and well explained. It was hard for me to understand the intersection observer docs and why my code wasn't running. Many Many many thanks