# Why I'm getting undefined while assigning a function call to a variable even when it is a synchronous call?

Tags: javascript, html, async-await, callback

I have a piece of code as this :

```js
function imp(user) {
  return console.log("user", user)
}

var msg = imp("Jenny")

console.log("msg", msg)
```

I'm getting an output as this :

```
user //for user log
undefined // for msg log
```

However I expect this `undefined` if the code was async, for example a setTimeout call inside the imp function as :

```
function imp(user) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("inside the timeout for ", user)
  }, 3000)
}
```

But since the very top code is sync, then still why it logs `undefined` ?

Isn't that equal to simply assigning a new variable (msg) to a function call?

Thanks for reading

Comment: `return console.log` will return undefined

Comment: why is that? It also returns undefined even I just do console.log without the return keyword

Comment: exactly. the return value of `console.log(...)` is undefined.

Comment: but even when I'm not using the return keyword?

Comment: @anshul: What value do you *expect* `msg` to have and why?

Comment: Please read [Does every Javascript function have to return a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337064/does-every-javascript-function-have-to-return-a-value)

Comment: @David I want it to either return the function signature itself if I'm logging just `msg` or call the function with the `console.log(...)` inside it when I'm calling as `msg()`

Comment: functions return by default `undefined` if you dont use the `return` keyword

Comment: @anshul: If you want `msg` to be the `imp` function then it would be: `var msg = imp;`  You're *invoking* the function.

Comment: @bill.gates So I believe that's a tricky slope here, if I don't use return keyword, then it would log undefined, if I do then console.log returns undefined by default?

Comment: @David Yes, exactly that's what i'm trying to do, but instead passing a user value as well as - `var msg = imp("Jenny")`

Comment: console.log returns undefined https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log?retiredLocale=de#return_value

Comment: @anshul: Are you looking for this?:  `var msg = () => imp("Jenny");` ?

Comment: @David yes, the same functionality as arrow signature, but can't we do it without an arrow function? It's just simply assigning a function call with params to a new variable

Comment: @anshul: Because, again, you are *invoking* the function.  That's what using parentheses after a function name does.  When you call `imp("Jenny")` you invoke the `imp` function and pass it the parameter `"Jenny"`.  If you're not expecting this to invoke the function then why do you expect `console.log("msg", msg)` to invoke the `console.log` function and not just return a reference to the `console.log` function?  Why would you expect that using parentheses does one thing in one case and another thing in another case?  Invoking a function is basic JavaScript syntax...

Comment: @David I understood, Thanks for the description. So If I do - `var msg = imp;` & later do `msg('jenny')` then it would invoke the function correct? Please put the comment as an answer. I would tick it off if you like.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the return of the console.log(), a console.log() returns undefined and not the message it just logged.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log